# How can we use the kafka connect truststore password in an abstract way in the KafkaConnector resource?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, solace, strimzi

We have a connect cluster of 3 nodes. We need couple of certificates in our connect cluster truststore. We have installed those certificates in the following way.

```yaml
...
spec:
  tls:
      trustedCertificates:
      - certificate: ca.crt
        secretName: my-cluster-cluster-ca-cert
      - secretName: root-cer
        certificate: RootCA.crt
      - certificate: IntermediateCA.crt
        secretName: inter-cer
      - secretName: solace-broker-secret
        certificate: secure-solace-broker.crt
...
```

As you know, after the three connect clusters spins up, the certificates has been installed into the following truststore `/tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12`. Also, we can found the randomly truststore password into the following file: `/tmp/strimzi-connect.properties`.

We direct the truststore path and the truststore password in the KafkaConnector resource file.

```yaml
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: solace-source-connector
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster
spec:
  class: com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    kafka.topic: solace-test
    sol.host: tcps://msdkjskdjsdfrdfjdffdhxu3n.messaging.solace.cloud:55443
    sol.username: my-solace-cloud-username
    sol.password: password
    sol.vpn_name: solaceservice
    sol.topics: try-me
    sol.message_processor_class: com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.msgprocessors.SolSampleSimpleMessageProcessor
    sol.ssl_trust_store: /tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12
    sol.ssl_trust_store_password: HARDCODED_RANDOM_PASSWORD
```

Right now we are getting inside into one of the connect cluster pod, get the password from the `/tmp/strimzi-connect.properties` file and then using the password in the `sol.ssl_trust_store_password` field.

My question:

**Is there any way to parametrize the password? Any encapsulated way to use the password (so that we do not need to get inside into the pod to know the password - expectation is, the kafkaconnector resouce would fecth the password from the `/tmp/strimzi-connect.properties` file, on which pod it is running)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer from the Slack channel by Jakub Scholz.

> The tls configuration you are using and the truststore are supposed to
> be used for communication between Connect and Kafka, not for the
> connectors. I think you have two options how to provide a truststore
> for the connector
>
> 1. You can use the same truststore as you are using now, but load the password using the FileConfigProvider - I think that should load the
>    right password on each connect node
> 2. You can just create your own secret with the truststore for the connector and load it into connect using this:
>    https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/using.html#assembly-kafka-connect-external-configuration-deployment-configuration-kafka-connect

And this is how I have implemented it:

1. Creating a custom keystore along with my certificates:

```sh
keytool -import -file RootCA.crt -alias root -keystore myTrustStore
```

2. Creating a Kubernetes secret with the trust store:

```sh
kubectl create secret generic my-trust-store --from-file=myTrustStore
```

3. loading the secret into the connect resource file:

```yaml
spec:
  ...
  externalConfiguration:
    volumes:
      - name: my-trust-store
        secret:
          secretName: my-trust-store
```

4. After the connect cluster pod spins up, the certificate will going to be available at /opt/kafka/external-configuration/my-trust-store/